# How can I get graphql to output this list of object for the client?

Tags: graphql

I have a graphql server, and I am trying to implement a query that will update the client with a list of nodes.

In nodes.js I have:

```
export const nodes = {
  "nodes": [
    {id: 1, "name": 'building_1', "hasStrobe": true},
    {id: 2, "name": 'building_2', "hasStrobe": false},
    {id: 3, "name": 'building_3', "hasStrobe": true}
  ]
}
```

My query in schema.js is as follows:

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  description: 'Root query object',
  fields() {
    return {
      message: {
        type: Message,
        resolve() {
          return getMessage();
        },
      },
      system: {
        type: System,
        resolve() {
          return getSystemInfo();
        },
      },
      nodes: {
        type: Nodes,
        resolve() {
          //console.log(nodes.nodes)
          return nodes.nodes;
        }
      },

      // alert: {
      //   type: Alert,
      //   resolve() {
      //     return 'poke';
      //   }
      // }
    };
  },
});
```

And my Nodes type is as follows:

```
const Nodes = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Nodes',
  description: 'List of zone nodes and their capabilities.',
  fields() {
    return {
      nodes: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve(msg) {
          console.log(msg)
          return msg;
        }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

When the query is run, it logs nodes.nodes correctly to the console:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'building_1', hasStrobe: true },
  { id: 2, name: 'building_2', hasStrobe: false },
  { id: 3, name: 'building_3', hasStrobe: true } ]
```

While the query output is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "system": {
      "uname": "4.11.5-2-ck-haswell\n",
      "time": "Thu Jun 22 2017 17:39:29 GMT-0500 (CDT)"
    },
    "nodes": {
      "nodes": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to process the data array in a way that will work to output the nodes.

Comment: As a side note, this implementation of graphql from ReactQL is wonderful.